# random forest have 0 training error?

Tags: random-forest, fitting

For a dataset $(X, y)$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. where $X$ is from some $i.i.d$ with $m \ll n$, i can easily fit a linear regression model with $0$ training error.

Now my question is, can i fit a random forest regressor achieve 0 training error?

Comment: Sure: your training set consists of two samples, random forest would easily learn to classify both perfectly.

Comment: Under what conditions? If your target variable is constant, then you can trivially fit pretty much any model with zero error. And conversely, no, you can't have zero error in OLS, unless your rules stipulate you can have any $X$ you want. So: what are you asking?

Comment: i guess, for a general random dataset, if simple linear regression can have 0 training error, not the two sample or all label the same case. can random forest achieve 0 training error?

Comment: cubist does cubic interpolation, so as long as your data was piecewise cubic in then you have a better chance for being able to do it there.  Many CART models have constant values per leaf tip, so they are different beasties, and you would need to have all the lines of separation being perpendicular to the axes.  If you do that you can get "perfect" fits.